# My regex pattern is failed

Tags: regex, preg-match

i need some help. My data;

```
{foreach $page_list as $page}
    <li><a href="" title="{$page->name}">{$page->name}</a></li>
{/foreach}
```

And my pattern;

```
~\{foreach\s\$(.+)\sas\s\$([^\{]+)\}([^\{]+)\{\/foreach\}~
```

But it's not working. What is wrong ?

Comment: What do you want to happen? What does "not working" mean? Please be specific with questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern with which you are trying to exclude the line between the two {foreach...} regions explicitly does not match '{' characters, but two are present in the string. Since that middle area's match is broken somewhere that doesn't get followed by a {/foreach}, the entire pattern fails to match.

That entire portion of the pattern should possibly be `.*` instead. Rely on backtracking to catch the closing `{/foreach}`. Of course, this will erroneously match an entire list as one thing, but regular expressions in general can't match quotes (without backreferences, which are technically non-regular and hurt performance), so you might need another parsing strategy entirely.

Comment: It seemed, `s (PCRE_DOTALL)` will be required as well